# Grabbing different heights and widths from images with same class and applying it to their siblings

Tags: jquery, css

I have a basically unlimited amount of images. The dimensions of each image is different (and also changes dynamically through percentages as the viewport size changes), and I need the sibling of each image to match these dimensions.

I've gotten JQuery to print the width of each image in the console, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the image's sibling div. Also, it would be nice if there was some way to watch for changes in viewport size, to make sure the sibling div always has the same dimensions as the image at all times, even when you resize the window.

HTML:

```
<a class="shop-item">

  <img class="thumbnail"/>

  <div class="product-information">
  </div>

</a>

  <a class="shop-item">

  <img class="thumbnail"/>

  <div class="product-information">
  </div>

</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".thumbnail").each(function() {
    var imgwidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    $(this).closest('.product-information').css('width', 'imgwidth');

    console.log(imgwidth)
  });
});
```

CodePen:
http://codepen.io/jonp/pen/yOrvwJ

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(this).closest('.product-information').css('width', 'imgwidth'); you are setting string 'imgwidth' as width value. Use var: imgwidth+'px'...

Comment: @nevermind Thanks for the reply. I've fixed this, but it doesn't seem like my selector is selecting the .product-information; it doesn't add any width value at all. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except problem mentioned in comment, you need another selector/method,

So, use next(), rather than closest():

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".thumbnail").each(function() {
    var imgwidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    $(this).next('.product-information').css('width', imgwidth+'px');

    console.log(imgwidth)
  });
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKEYXX